# Angular: How can I pass a background image URL through HTML rather than CSS?

Tags: html, css, angular

**The Scenario:**

I have an element in my Angular app that I want to add a background image to. At the moment I have this:

```
<div class={{background-class}}></div>
```

where `background-class` is, for example, "background-style-1", which is in my stylesheet like this:

```
background-style-1 {
  background-image: url(../../../../assets/images/contextmenu/person.png);
}
```

The element successfully displays the image, and if I query it, it shows this:
[image]

**The Problem:**

I don't want to hard-code all the background image URLs into my stylesheet. Instead, I want to just pass the URL into the HTML tag.

**What I've Tried**

```
<div style="background-image: url(../../../../assets/images/contextmenu/person.png)"></div>
```

This fails to display the image, and when I query the element, it shows this:

[image]

**What I Want To Know:**

Why does passing the image URL as an inline style property not work, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle):

HTML:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'}"
```

TS:

```
image = "assets/images/contextmenu/person.png"
```

Comment: Hi Adrita, unfortunately it's still not working. The image doesn't load, and when I hover over the element it says: background-image: url(../../../../assets/images/contextmenu/person.png);
Is there any other info I can give you to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the image path is correct? Simply test it by binding image src

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamicaly set the background image from the html using this syntax : `[style.someproperty]="'somevalue'"`. In your case, it can look something like this.

```
<div [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + url + ')'"></div>
```

This will take the value of `url` ( defined in your controller)  as the url for the background image.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, unfortunately it's still not working. The image doesn't load, and when I hover over the element it says: background-image: url(../../../../assets/images/contextmenu/person.png); Is there any other info I can give you to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the image  `../../../../assets/images/contextmenu/person.png` exists ?

Comment: Yep, double-checked ;)

Comment: I'm not sure but it might have something to do with the way Angular bundle your files. Remember that when you load your site, you are  loading compiled file from the `dist` folder. So if your  `dist` folder doesn't have your image is it, it is not available to the browser.

Comment: if everythings is in `~/projects/somefolders/yourapp/dist/` then `../../../../` goes back all the way to the `project` folder ( in this example ) @RNdev

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngStyle` directive to bind styles dynamically on html elements

In component set your path variable

```
path = '../../../../assets/images/contextmenu/person.png'
```

use it in template like below

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + path + ')'}"></div>
```

Try this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxk5dr

Documention link for ngStyle

https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: Hi Mamta, unfortunately it's still not working. The image doesn't load, and when I hover over the element it says: background-image: url(../../../../assets/images/contextmenu/person.png);
Is there any other info I can give you to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz link with some sample code of yours

Comment: I don't think you can upload images to stackblitz. My code is exactly the same as yours in your stackblitz link, except that rather than using "https..." as the URL, I'm using the ref to a local file. Do you know if it's possible to upload images to stackblitz to replicate my scenario? I don't think I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `[ngStyle]` or `[style.backgroundImage]` to bind dynamic styles.

and it's better to pass image/icon name to the component.

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(path/to/icons' + iconName + ')'}"
```

or smililarly

```
[style.backgroundImage]= 'url(path/to/icons' + iconName + ')'
```

and the iconName  would be

```
const iconName = 'logo.svg';
```

PS: Ensure that `logo.svg` is present in the given path.